# How to add video-ads?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have read that WP8 now supports video-ads.
Through the pubCenter I can only create `Text / Image` ads, but no video-ads.

Nowhere on the internet I could find any info on this. So how can I add video-ads to my app?

Answer (score 0):

You don't choose a specific kind the advertises do that for you.

Here is an article about it
http://advertising.microsoft.com/en-us/blogpost/128708/microsoft-advertising-blog/microsoft-advertising-releases-new-ad-sdk-to-enable-enhanced-rich-media-experiences-on-window

Here is the MSDN Documentation for the new AD SDK
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/advertising-mobile-windows-phone-sdk-intro(v=msads.20).aspx

Comment: I already visited those sites. Like I said, I can't find the option for video ads in the pubcenter.

Comment: It is automatic. no optuon

Comment: @AnthonyRussell Its automatic in the sense, video ads will be coming automatically along with text_image ad?

Comment: 404 not found on the link now :(